# spring-ws: "Cannot map endpoint on registration key [{urn:x.y.z}Req] there's already endpoint" while trying to create current and legacy ws endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, spring-ws

I am using Spring-boot to create 2 Webservice endpoints.

One with the current version of my webservice and one with the previous one. I have generated the mapping classes of each webservice version under different packages, but the wsdl namespace and operations defined by the current and previous versions are the same.

This seems to be the reason for the error I get:

```
Cannot map endpoint on registration key [{urn:x.y.z}Req] there's already endpoint
```

which according to the stacktrace is caused by [spring's AbstractMapBasedEndpointMapping.registerEndpoint()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/v3.1.5/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/AbstractMapBasedEndpointMapping.java#L136) when trying to register the second endpoint, because the registration key (generated by the namespace / operation combination) is the same.

What would be a workaround on the above issue? I want to run both endpoints on the same VM.

Comment: I dont know how your WSDL is loaded, but maybe it is possible to write two spring profiles. You could set different web server ports in this profiles and specifiy the wsdl locations. Than you can start your application twice on your VM. Of course you need routing and load balancing. Maybe take a look at spring-cloud-gateway. They have relative easy path rewrite functions. And the resource consumption is higher e.g. DB connections pools, memmory. etc.